# Display query on BIRT report layout

Tags: eclipse, reporting, birt

How could I display a data set's query on a Birt Report's layout? I have a data set that errors out after some scripting. I would like to somehow view the query that is being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods to display the queryText. you should take the second one.

1. You can display the queryText of a Data Set by creating a new Data Item in your report. Go to `Properties -> Advanced` and select for the property `Data set` the Data Set you want the queryText to display for. Then you write into the expression `this.queryText`. This will output the SQL-Query text of your data set. However in a small test of mine scripting changes to the queryText are not reflected in this way.
2. After your scripting in the Data Sets script Tab, add the following line to save the modified queryText to a global variable `reportContext.setGlobalVariable("testName", this.queryText);`
   create a new Data Item in your report and enter the following expression: `reportContext.getGlobalVariable("testName");` this will output your modified SQL-Query Text.